# Navigating up from an activity to a specific fagment in the parent activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I'm trying to make the UP button provide back navigation to a specific fragment in the parent activity.

**Activity1** contatins `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`. You can launch **Activity2** from `FragmentB`.

**Activity1** is declared as the parent of **Activity2** in the Manifest file.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.Activity2"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.Activity1" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.Activity1" />
</activity>
```

When you're in Activity2 and press UP button, I want you to return to `FragmentB` in **Activity1**.
Instead, it returns to FragmentA (because it's the default fragment in Activity1).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you finish Activity A when you launch Activity B, otherwise you would still have the fragment B visible int the Activity A (as you left it). But try to put an extra in the intent of the Activity B that launches the Activity A that says which fragment should be active in that Activity. That way, when the Activity A is created, you can check the bundle, check if there is any information about which fragment should be visible, and, if so, set the fragment as visible.

Comment: This is the exact way I would do this too.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is I do not launch ActivityA directly. Android takes care of the up-navigation, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes and no. Although it handles the action, you can override certain methods that will be called when the "UP" action takes place. See here:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp

Comment: So you're saying I should just launch ActivityA with an intent from `onOptionsItemSelected()` method?

Comment: No, I am saying that you could intercept the intent in that method and put an extra in it :)